# HTML - Z-index with transition

Tags: html, css, django, figure

I got a problem with my html project. When I hoover an image it gets larger but it does not cover images next to each other. (only left one)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3XDF.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A35fQ.png

CSS:

```
.photo {

  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 120px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  will-change: transform;
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: inline-flex;

}

.photo img {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}

.photo figcaption {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.photo:nth-child(even) {
  transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(0.8);
}

.photo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(2.0);
  z-index: 10;

}
```

HTML

```
{% for i in zdjecie %}

   <figure class="photo" >
    <img src="{{i.url}}"
         alt="Kotek Robert">
    <figcaption>
      {{i.title}}
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` won't function as expected on objects with `static` positioning.

Add `position: relative` to your `.photo` elements to fix the issue:

```css
.photo {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 120px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  will-change: transform;
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: inline-flex;
  
  position: relative; /* add this */
}

.photo img {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}

.photo figcaption {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.photo:nth-child(even) {
  transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(0.8);
}

.photo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(2.0);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="photo">
  <img src="{{i.url}}" alt="Kotek Robert">
  <figcaption>
    {{i.title}}
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```